# Access a local class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, import

I'm having trouble accessing a class (actually several classes) from other classes, and modules, all in the same vb.net (Asp.net) project.

Here is an example of one of the classes I cannot Import or access:
(This file is clsPitch.vb in the \App_Code folder)

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Public Class clsPitch
    Public MyStuff As String
End Class
```

In another class in the same project:

```
Dim ThisClass As clsPitch
```

This gives the following error:
"Type 'clsPitch' is not defined."

```
Imports MyProject.clsPitch
```

This gives the following error:
"Namespace or type specified in the imports 'MyProject.clsPitch' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases."

When I type "Imports.MyProject." none of these classes show up in intellisense.

I have not specified any NameSpaces (My understanding is everything should be in one NameSpace for the entire project).

What's strange is that I have another class that is basically defined the same, and it works fine (I can access it and import it).

Comment: Right click on the .vb file in the App_Code folder and take a look at its properties. Make sure the `Build Action` is set to `Compile`

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was at a complete loss.  I'm not sure how I wound up with an App_Code folder in my ASP.Net Windows Forms app, but I had no idea the folder names had meaning.  And, I created all of the classes the exact same way, so I can't explain why some had the correct build action, and some didn't.  I created a new folder, placed my class files in it, set the build action to compile, and it all works.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries! Have added as an answer so others can find.

Comment: You need a `Namespace` for the code in your clsPitch.vb file.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the .vb file in the App_Code folder and take a look at its properties. Make sure the `Build Action` is set to `Compile`.